# Jquery DataTable auto scroll to bottom on load

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the [jQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/) plug-in and can not see to find a way to make it scroll to the bottom of the table when the data loads via AJAX.

So the basic layout of my page has two 3 jQuery DataTables on it. From what I see by inspecting the rendered code is that the plug-in will create a div wrapper with an id of "myTableid_wrapper" with two children a header and the table.

Now if the table is triggers the scrolling ability then the table will again be wrapped in another div with overflow:hidden so the table can be scrolled.

This div has a class name of "dataTables_scrollBody". Here is an example of a table that has not triggered the scroll feature.

```
<div id="myTable1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" >
  <div id="case_activity_table_filter">no worried about this guy</div>
    <table id="myTable1" >does not matter whats in here</table>
</div>
```

Here is the general layout of a table that has triggered the scroll feature of the plugin. As you can see the div with the class "dataTables_scrollBody" is auto-generated by the plugin.

```
<div id="myTable2_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" >
  <div id="case_activity_table_filter">no worried about this guy</div>
  <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow:hidden" >
    <table id="myTable2" >does not matter whats in here</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both of these tables reside on the same page. Both of these tables may or may not have the scroll div.

Is there way to target class "dataTables_scrollBody" and have it scroll bottom when the table is created via AJAX?

Comment: There are several data table plusing for jQuery. Care to share exactly which one you're using?

Comment: @j08691, I've updated their post, I recognize the classes as http://datatables.net/

Comment: @j08691 It really doesn't matter which one it is anyway since I need to target <div class="dataTables_scrollBody"> and make it scroll bottom. Maybe I should just change the plugin itself and have it add an id also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assuming you initialized the datatable like this:

```
var oTable = jQuery('#myTable1').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sScrollY": "200",
    "bScrollCollapse": true
});
```

you can just do:

```
oTable.parent().scrollTop(9999);
```

you can increase the amount to scroll if you will have more data, or there's probably a way to find out the height of the table including the overflow part.

with ajax you might have to put the scrollTop code in the "fnInitComplete" callback function, so it's executed after the table is rendered.

...

Another idea: maybe you can reverse the order of the rows with aaSorting, then you don't have to do any scrolling.

Comment: when scrolling up its also loading how i stop to load on only scroll down

Answer (score 0):

If somebody like me end up here looking up how to comfortably scroll the js datatable, I would strongly recomend taking look at `scrollTo` library, which perfectly does the job:

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo][1](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)

example usage:

```
$('<here whole datatable>').scrollTo( '<here target eg td>', 1 );
```