# jQuery Datatables scroll to bottom when a row is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, datatables

I'd like my DataTable to scroll to the bottom whenever a row is added. I have tried multiple *fixes* for this problem, but none of them work.

Tested solutions:

- [How to load table in Datatables and have it scroll to last record automatically on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486319/how-to-load-table-in-datatables-and-have-it-scroll-to-last-record-automatically)
- [Jquery DataTable auto scroll to bottom on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998166/jquery-datatable-auto-scroll-to-bottom-on-load)

Among others...

I think that what separates my case from the others, is that I am using `DataTable` with the `D` capitalized.

Anyway, here is my current code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
          "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) 
          {
             $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
          },
          "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "scrollY":        $(window).height()/1.5,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false,
   });

   for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
      table.row.add([ 
         i,
         'action'+i,
      ]);
   }  

   table.draw();

   table.rowReordering();
```

It would be nice if the table scrolled to bottom whenever a new row is added to it..

Comment: Have you tried using anchors ?

Comment: No, never heard of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### SOLUTION

To scroll to the bottom of the table, use the code below:

```
var $scrollBody = $(table.table().node()).parent();
$scrollBody.scrollTop($scrollBody.get(0).scrollHeight);
```

### DEMO

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
         $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
        console.log($(row).closest('table').parent());
      },
      "scrollY":        $(window).height()/1.5,
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "paging": false
   });

   $('#btn-add').click(function(){    
      for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
         table.row.add([ 
            i,
            i + '.2',
            i + '.3',
            i + '.4',
            i + '.5',
            i + '.6'
         ]);
      }  
   
      table.draw();      

      // Scroll to the bottom
      var $scrollBody = $(table.table().node()).parent();
      $scrollBody.scrollTop($scrollBody.get(0).scrollHeight);
   });
  
   table.rowReordering();
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>jQuery DataTables</title>  
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mpryvkin/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/95b44786cb41cf37bd3ad39e39e1d216277bd727/media/js/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
<button id="btn-add" type="button">Add records</button>
  
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working fine. You can adjust $scrollBody.get(0).scrollHeight value by subtracting too..